# tel in openURL not working properly

Tags: iphone, openurl, tel

In my app I want to call to selected number. For this I have following code

```
 +(void)makeCallToSelectedContact:(NSString*)phoneNo{

    NSMutableString *phoneNumber = [NSMutableString stringWithString:phoneNo];

    [phoneNumber replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " 
                                 withString:@"" 
                                    options:NSLiteralSearch 
                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [phoneNumber length])];
    [phoneNumber replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"(" 
                                 withString:@"" 
                                    options:NSLiteralSearch 
                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [phoneNumber length])];
    [phoneNumber replaceOccurrencesOfString:@")" 
                                 withString:@"" 
                                    options:NSLiteralSearch 
                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [phoneNumber length])];

    NSLog(@"phoneNumber => %@",phoneNumber);
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:+%@",phoneNumber]]]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:+%@",phoneNumber]]];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Unable to open");
        [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Alert" andMessage:@"This Device Doesn't Support Call Functionality"]; 
    }
}
```

Lets say if I have ph no like +91 1234567890 , then it will call the number correctly. But if I have number without + & country code like 1234567890 then it is converting it to +12 34567890 which is wrong phone number. Here is my console log

```
    2012-04-05 19:13:37.960 Search[22453:11003] phoneNumber => +911234567890

2012-04-05 19:13:47.928 Search[22453:11003] phoneNumber => 1234567890
```

What I am missing ? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the '+' when you create the URL - Look :

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:+%@",phoneNumber]]]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:+%@",phoneNumber]]];
}
```